# Angular directive for radioButton list

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a list of objects called: 'programs',

Each program has 'Min' and 'Max' properties

I ng-repeat on this list to create a list of radioButtons for all programs,

But - I dont wan to show the program if some number input is not between min and

max of this program. so I send to function to check if program is enable :

```
  <div ng-repeat="p in programs" >
    <div  ng-if="ifEnable(p)">
        <input  type="radio" >
        <label for="{{program.ID}}">{{p.Name}} </label>
    </div>
   </div>
```

It works. but I want to do like this - if just one program is enable , I want to show this program in another place in page instead of the radio list.

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZblxzPC7SHO0dz62U10P?p=preview) - if you type '4' in input you see that just one program is display in list, so I want show it in another place and dont show the radio list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a filter on the list make it more simple to do :

See it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rt5qLXnbNpxh0EfD2UJs?p=preview)

**The filter :**

```
app.filter('inRange', function() {
  return function(programs, value) {
    var finalList = [];
    angular.forEach(programs, function(program){
      if (value <= program.Max && value >= program.Min){
        console.log("true !");
        finalList.push(program);
      }
    })
    return finalList;
  };
});
```

**Its use :**

```
programs | inRange : num
```

Now the logic for the single program

The bottom `ng-repeat` look like this :

```
 <div ng-show="(programs | inRange : num).length > 1" ng-repeat="p in programs | inRange : num" >
    <input  type="radio" >
    <label for="{{program.ID}}">{{p.Name}} - min: {{p.Min}} - max: {{p.Max}}</label>
 </div>
```

And i added an other one on the top with a different condition :

```
<h1>
  <div ng-show="(programs | inRange : num).length === 1" ng-repeat="p in programs | inRange : num" >
    <input  type="radio" >
    <label for="{{program.ID}}">{{p.Name}} - min: {{p.Min}} - max: {{p.Max}}</label>
  </div>
</h1>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: cool ! thats exactly what I need.It works perfect! but I wonder if this is the best way to do it. because the programs list depend on a lot of inputs in page, not just the number  and this filter occure  a lot of times in 1 second. so do you have any other idea to improve performance?

Comment: @BrMe Yeah sure, could you just add this part in your question ? (Exemple with multiple inputs). You could also use a brand new list like "filteredPrograms" and trigger the filter with a "ng-change" on the inputs. would be at least cleaner :) ! If you want some exemple update the plunker with your use cases then give it back to me and i'll take care of this.

Comment: here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrPuSxT9YCdiVOdfMS6v) with new example, I have a list of ages,each age can choose birthDate(I put in example just number input to choose age but acyually I have a datepicker) and the program should display just if age is between min and max, and also have connected user permissions array with id of programs he can see and program should display just if the user has permissions to see it.

Comment: @BrMe What about this ? http://plnkr.co/edit/Cam1b5yC4eYvsi1e9RP6?p=preview I modified the filter to take an array of object and i added a ng-change on the inputs.

Comment: yes, thats ok. it works but I hope the performance are ok. because it happens so many time in 1 second..10x!

Comment: 10x ? You mean that the input values changes 10x per seconds ? (Angular is pretty strong in term of performances, only really big apps can put it down) I locked the filter in my last exemple. It only trigger when an input value change (I keep the filtered list in a var)